# Use of mapply() to prevent double nested loop

Tags: r, mapply

I am trying to compute the density of a bivariate normal distribution for sets of x and y values. Using `mapply()`, I want to iterate over a set of means (`means`, `means2`) and each x and y values specified in the `lower =` and `upper =` arguments. I want to use `mapply()` to provide a nested for-loop (one loop for elements in `lower` and `upper`, one for elements in `means`, and one for elements in `means2`.

```
# Params needed for pmvnorm()
sigma1 <- matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 2), 2)
means <- seq(from = 0, to = 15, by = 0.5)
means_2 <- seq(from = 10, to = 15, by = 0.5)

mapply(
  pmvnorm,
  lower = c(
    c(-Inf, 7, 10),
    c(-Inf, seq(from = -3, to = 4, by = 1))
  ),
  upper = c(
    c(7, 10, Inf),
    c(seq(from = -3, to = 4, by = 1), Inf)
    ),
  mean = c(
    means,
    means_2
    ),
  MoreArgs = list(sigma = sigma1, keepAttr = FALSE)
  )
)
```

However, this does produces the following error message:

```
Error in checkmvArgs(lower = lower, upper = upper, mean = mean, corr = corr,  : 
  ‘diag(sigma)’ and ‘lower’ are of different length
```

For simply calculating the density for one set of x and y values and means, the following code works:

```
pmvnorm(lower = c(0, 1), upper = c(7, 10),
        mean = c(1, 1), sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 2), 2), keepAttr = FALSE)
```

Could someone provide me pointers as to how do fix this error?

Comment: Also, your `lower/upper` is a single vector input.  Is that what you meant i.e. `c(
    c(-Inf, 7, 10),
    c(-Inf, seq(from = -3, to = 4, by = 1))
  )` is a single vector

Comment: For non-iteration use cases, you specify `lower = c(x_low, y_low), upper = c(x_high, y_high) ...` Not sure if how I did it works when iterating over those elements in the vector.

Comment: Can you show your code for a single case ie.. without the loop in mapply

Comment: edited it in my original question. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: The help page states that `lower`, `upper` and `mean` have length n and `sigma` dimension n. That's not the case with your code.

Comment: What i meant is that suppose you are using a single case, how does the code look like

Comment: Based on the single code, may be you need to split so that it becomes length 2 for each iteration i.e. `asplit(matrix(c(
    c(-Inf, 7, 10),
    c(-Inf, seq(from = -3, to = 4, by = 1))
  ), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE), 1)`

Comment: @akrun, that does not work: `Error in checkmvArgs(lower = lower, upper = upper, mean = mean, corr = corr,  :   ‘lower’ is not a numeric vector`. @Rui Barradas, how would I resolve that?

Comment: That code was to show that you can split so that it returns a vector of length 2.  I don't know the order you wanted to create.  Also, the same goes on for upper and mean

Comment: As akrun has stated, Your code will not work. You need to state the pair of lower and upper values should be, then the pair of means. Note that you are working with bivariate data, thus each element MUST be a pair. Otherwise it wont work

Comment: I understand that, but I am not sure how to do that as the function expects a numeric vector of size `n`. Using `asplit()` and `matrix()` will return a list.